# Create contour lines from a WCS file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour, wcs

I am currently working on a mapping project in QGIS, and the only good DEM model I can find of SE Norway is a high-res WCS link that I have uploaded into my project. I would really like to create contour lines,

So I was wondering if there is any way to do this with a DEM in WCS format. Everything I've found online deals with raster and vector files.

Comment: WCS is not a format. It is a protocol for requesting and delivering coverage data, for example rasters. Once you have downloaded and saved DEM from WCS service you can continue with the raster workflow. But as far as I know QGIS is rather useless WCS client. Use GDAL instead or learn to write the WCS GetCoverage requests manually.

Comment: If you want a proper answer and the WCS service is open please give a link to it.

Comment: What formats does the WCS give access to? You can check from the GetCapabilities request...